# when i install lxml on my mac, "gcc-4.2 not found, using clang instead" shown in the installation process

Tags: python-2.7, lxml, llvm-gcc

when i install lxml on my mac, "gcc-4.2 not found, using clang instead" shown in the installation process.

I just type in the following command, and get the above anwser, how can i specify gcc-4.2 with llvm-gcc-4.2?

```
python setup.py build
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a soft link but clang is the default system compiler on OS X so you should probably be using that unless you have a very good reason not to.